# Getting Symfony 2 version from withing a service?

Tags: session, symfony, request, locale

I need to get the current locale from within a service, both for Symfony 2.0.x (uses `Session`) and Symfony 2.1.x (uses `Request`).

I would do sometthing like:

```php
if(version_compare(Symfony::VERSION, '2.1.0') < 0) {
    $obj = $this->get('session');
}
else {
    $obj = $this->get('request');
}

$locale = $obj->getLocale();
```

But there is no `Symfony::VERSION` constant. Any idea? Apart using `is_callable` or something strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
echo Kernel::VERSION . "\n";
```

Not sure if this is the recommend way or not but it works.  The kernel class is actually defined in the bootstrap.cache class so VERSION is updated whenever you update your Symfony source.

Also exposes:

```
const VERSION         = '2.1.4-DEV';
const VERSION_ID      = '20100';
const MAJOR_VERSION   = '2';
const MINOR_VERSION   = '1';
const RELEASE_VERSION = '4';
const EXTRA_VERSION   = 'DEV';
```

Comment: Thank you! Which one will be compatible with version_compare?

Comment: VERSION would be compatible though in your case you only need to check the MINOR_VERSION.

Comment: Seems like there should be an easy to inject the version into a service but I have not found it.

Comment: How about an extension class that gets that value and injects it into the service definition? `$container->getDefition('foo')->addArgument($value)`.